# WSO2 AM WebSocket API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created a Node API URL that emits a web socket event when called and configured my client side application to listen for the event.

This functionality works correctly when I call the Node URL directly.

I then created a web socket api in WSO2 AM 2.1.0 and added the Node URL as the endpoint for the API to hit. But now when the client starts polling, I receive a connection refused error. Is there any solution or documentation that I can refer for configuring the API for WSO2.

Comment: Can you attach your error logs here?

Comment: link to the AM error logs : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lbvERXRg4l608JqG9QbPMV8LbBuEWHl0